How to band pass wind data then use quiver correctly
I have an hourly resolution wind dataset contains dates, wind speed, and wind direction (come from). I would like to apply a 2 - 7 days band pass filter then quiver it to get a timeseries of the wind magnitude.
Portion of my dataset as .mat files:
date:  
734417.666666667  
734417.708333333
734417.750000000
734417.791666667
734417.833333333
734417.875000000
734417.916666667
734417.958333333
734418
734418.041666667
WindSpeed:
11.2000000000000
11.4000000000000
12
11.4000000000000
12.1000000000000
11.9000000000000
11.2000000000000
11.7000000000000
15.1000000000000
15.5000000000000
WindDirection:
276
271
267
260
256
261
275
283
281

This is the code I used in matlab to band pass filter the wind data and then quiver it:
wind7S= windHr.WindSpeed- pl33tn(windHr.WindSpeed,1,168);
wind27S= pl33tn(wind7S,1,48);
HrDir = deg2rad(windHr.WindDirection -180); % change the direction to 'blow towards'
U_hr = wind27S .* cos(HrDir); % Eastward
V_hr = wind27S .* sin(HrDir); % Northward
U_7day = U_hr - pl33tn(U_hr, dt, 168);
V_7day = V_hr - pl33tn(V_hr, dt, 168);
U_bp27 = pl33tn(U_7day, dt, 48);
V_bp27 = pl33tn(V_7day, dt, 48);
quiver(datenum(date), zeros(size(date)), U_bp27, V_bp27);

However, when I plot the quiver for the band pass filtered data and the original data, I have a plot like this:

It confuses me of why the band pass filtered quiver look so different than the hourly resolution. Is it suppose be to the right plot for me to identify any weather events or anyone has ideas on how to fix it if it is not correct? Thanks!
